# Call to member function on a non-object problem

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem with this:

```
function do_login() {
global $db;

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $row = $db->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($row)) {
        if($username == $rows['username'] && $password == $rows['password']) {
            $_SESSION['Logedin'] = true;
            echo 'yah';
        }else{
            echo 'Neh';
        };
    }
}
```

because it gives me this error: Fatal error:
 **Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\falco\admin\class\auth.php on line 79**

I dont know what I am missing! 
Thank you for your help

Comment: You know [little bobby tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain), do you?

Comment: And avoid using 'global', it's definitely enemy of each coder. Function have no arguments - pass $db there.

Answer (score 1):

`$db` is probably not initialized. Issue a `var_dump($db);` in the previous line to see what it contains.

Also, your code is open to a full on sql injection... Sanitize `$_GET`/`$_POST` before using anything in it in queries. Try this username, for instance:

```
$_POST['username'] = "admin' OR 1 = 1 OR username='"
```

Comment: the problem was that the class was initialized after this function so now it works, but I am not really good at security but I am going to do something about it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess (and it's only a guess) is that when you're calling off to connect to the database, you're getting an error code or a false back instead of a database object. And you're not checking for this condition, and later on using it like a normal variable. And of course, an int or false or whatever doesn't have the query method.

This is only a guess.